# Glitch in Filling?

Tags: plotting, bugs, filling

**Bug introduced in 8.0 and persisting through 12.0 or later**

---

I ran into a problem while plotting and I was able to narrow it to this.  Before I start "spelunking" I'd like to know if I am overlooking something or if this is a problem others have worked through.

Here is my data:

```
x = {{20, 15.3, 11.9, 8.8}, {16.5, 12.5, 9.2, 6.5}, {10.5, 8.5}};
```

I create a plot with filling between the two complete lines and it works as expected:

```
ListLogPlot[x, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {{1, 4}, All},
  Filling -> {
    1 -> {{2}, Brown}
  }
]
```

[image]

However when I add filling between the second line and the third (incomplete) one it breaks:

```
ListLogPlot[x, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {{1, 4}, All},
  Filling -> {
    1 -> {{2}, Brown},
    2 -> {{3}, Gray}
  }
]
```

[image]

I was expecting:

[image]

Comment: It arises from `ListPlot`, which `ListLogPlot` calls.  That's as far as I could go, which perhaps you have already discovered.  Does not happen with `x = {Range[5, 2, -1], Range[4, 1, -1], Range[3, 2, -1]}`, but it does happen with `x = {0, 1, 2} + 2 {Range[5, 2, -1], Range[4, 1, -1], Range[3, 2, -1]}`.  A clue for a developer, I suppose.

Comment: Seems to be related to the last point of the first line being lower than the second to last point of the second curve. Try this `Manipulate[
 ListLinePlot[{{10, 10, a}, {b, b, 0}, {0, 0}}, 
  Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, Brown}, 2 -> {{3}, Gray}},
  PlotRange -> {{1, 3}, {0, 11}}],
 {{a, 7}, 0, 10}, {{b, 5}, 1, 9}]`

Comment: @SimonWoods Looks like you nailed it.  Would you be so kind as to submit that example to support for me?

Comment: Bug report now sent

Comment: The bug is still there in 10.0.2.

Comment: @Sjoerd Thanks.  Do you know when this first appeared?  I am guessing 10.0.0?

Comment: 8 and 9 have the same problem.

Comment: @Sjoerd Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

Changing the order of lists restore the filling

```
x = {{10.5, 8.5}, {20, 15.3, 11.9, 8.8}, {16.5, 12.5, 9.2, 6.5}};

ListLogPlot[x, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {{1, 5}, All}, 
 Filling -> {1 -> {{3}, Brown}, 2 -> {{3}, Gray}}]
```

[image]

Comment: This does work in v10.0.1. (+1) Any idea what's going on?  As far as I could tell from `Trace` the `Polygon` sprang fully formed from the head of Zeus.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Unfortunately, I don't know. Obviously, it is a bug in filling (choice of points for polygons is corrupted).

Answer (score 6):

Reversing the list in the `Filling` option makes it work (Mmav9):

```
ListLogPlot[x, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {{1, 4}, All}, 
            Filling -> {2 -> {{3}, Gray}, 1 -> {{2}, Brown}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Probably a bug :)

Works also with more series, apparently without problems:

```
x = {{20, 15.3, 11.9, 8.8}, {16.5, 12.5, 9.2, 6.5}, {10.5, 8.5}, {25, 22, 15}}; 
ListLogPlot[x, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {{1, 4}, All}, 
            Filling -> {1 -> {{4}, Blue}, 2 -> {{3}, Gray}, 1 -> {{2}, Brown}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Unfortunately neither form shown works in v10.  The first looks like http://i.stack.imgur.com/i93iP.png while the second does not show the brown filling.  Bug, I guess. :-/

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The really strange thing is that your original "bug" does show up in V9, while my rearranged list works. They bugged the walkaround :)

Answer (score 4):

The problem applies also to `ListPlot` and is related to the fact that all the datasets have exactly identical abscissas of the second point (which is the last point of the bottom line). To demonstrate this, at first I add the explicit abscissas into the dataset (the same bug persists):

```
x = {{20, 15.3, 11.9, 8.8}, {16.5, 12.5, 9.2, 6.5}, {10.5, 8.5}};
x = MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], Log@#1} &, #] & /@ x;
ListPlot[x, Joined -> True, Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, Brown}, 2 -> {{3}, Gray}}]
```

> [image: plot]

Now I perturb the abscissa of the second point in the first list:

```
x[[1, 2, 1]] += 2 $MachineEpsilon;
ListPlot[x, Joined -> True, Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, Brown}, 2 -> {{3}, Gray}}]
```

> [image: plot]

The same result can be achieved by perturbing the second point in any other list.

Now if I add third point to the last line, the bug appears again:

```
AppendTo[x[[-1]], {3, 2}]
ListPlot[x, Joined -> True, Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, Brown}, 2 -> {{3}, Gray}}]
```

> [image: plot]

And the remedy is the same, we should perturb the third point in any line:

```
x[[1, 3, 1]] += 2 $MachineEpsilon;
ListPlot[x, Joined -> True, Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, Brown}, 2 -> {{3}, Gray}}]
```

> [image: plot]