# ListLinePlot Filling Wrong

Tags: plotting, bugs, filling

**Bug introduced in 8 or earlier and persisting through 12.0**

---

I used `ListLinePlot` to plot data from .csv files. However, the y-values from Graph 1 do not match to the y-values from Graph 2, which I think, is the problem in my graph. Image of the problem linked.

[image]

What do I have to do, to get a smooth filling between the two graphs? The best way for defining the filling area would be a straight line between the last points on the two graphs.

Note: The "highest" point on Graph 1 doesn't exist. It is added by *Mathematica*, when I'm using the filling option.

EDIT: Code added. Normally there are 5 Graphs in 1 Chart, but the filling should only be done between the "highest" and the "lowest" graphs, to show some kind of scatter band.

EDIT2: Thank you very much! I can't set your answer to the one which helped me, since there seems to be a problem with my login. The Polygon Workaround is really helpful!!!

Code: http://pastebin.com/yPbv3Swm

Data Example Graph 1: http://pastebin.com/raJdP5HF
Data Example Graph 2: http://pastebin.com/ywDbMWkP
Data Example Graph 3 (New): http://pastebin.com/G577G9gS

Comment: Please add the code you used to generate the graph, and a sample of your data.

Comment: The data you posted doesn't seem to be the data you plotted

Comment: It looks like you created two accounts. You should ping the moderators and have them merged, that way you get the full benefits of the reputation you earned.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have distilled a minimal dataset reproducing the problem:

```
data = {{{45.904`, 227.46`}, {46.012`, 222.72`}, {46.076`, 215.51`}, {46.107`, 
     206.26`}, {46.119`, 196.15`}, {46.119`, 186.97`}, {46.118`, 178.5`}, {46.104`, 
     168.16`}, {46.079`, 156.43`}}, {{45.912`, 212.72`}, {45.976`, 205.51`}, {46.007`, 
     196.26`}, {46.019`, 186.15`}, {46.019`, 176.97`}, {46.018`, 168.5`}, {46.004`, 
     158.16`}, {45.979`, 146.43`}}};
simplePlot = ListLinePlot[data]
filledPlot = ListLinePlot[data, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]
```

> [image: plot]
>
> [image: plot]

Let us look at the first `Line` inside of the plots:

```
Cases[Normal@simplePlot, _Line, -1][[1]]
Cases[Normal@filledPlot, _Line, -1][[1]]
Complement[%[[1]], %%[[1]]]
```

> ```
> Line[{{45.904, 227.46}, {46.012, 222.72}, {46.076, 215.51}, {46.107, 206.26}, {46.119, 
>    196.15}, {46.119, 186.97}, {46.118, 178.5}, {46.104, 168.16}, {46.079, 156.43}}]
>
> Line[{{45.904, 227.46}, {45.912, 227.109}, {46.012, 222.72}, {45.979, 226.438}, {46.076, 
>    215.51}, {46.107, 206.26}, {46.119, 196.15}, {46.119, 186.97}, {46.118, 
>    178.5}, {46.104, 168.16}, {46.079, 156.43}}]
>
> {{45.912, 227.109}, {45.979, 226.438}}
> ```

Indeed there are two additional points in positions `2` and `4` in the case of the filled plot which are absent in the original dataset. The second extra point creates the obvious artifact on the plot; this point also is included in the `Polygon` which represents filling between the lines (at position `9`):

```
poly = Cases[Normal@filledPlot, _Polygon, -1]
```

> ```
> {Polygon[{{45.912, 212.72}, {45.976, 205.51}, {46.007, 196.26}, {46.019, 186.15}, {46.019,
>      176.97}, {46.018, 168.5}, {46.004, 158.16}, {45.979, 146.43}, {45.979, 
>     226.438}, {46.012, 222.72}, {45.912, 227.109}}]}
> ```

Apart of the incorrect extra point the `Polygon` is self-intersecting and its set of points simply does not allow to create correct vertical filling between the lines:

```
Graphics[{LightBlue, poly, Black, MapIndexed[Text[#2[[1]], #] &, poly[[1, 1]]]}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

> [image: plot]

So addition of the `Filling` option makes both the lines and the filling on the plot incorrect. This is a bug and I recommend to report it to the official technical support.

Here is a workaround which demonstrates the correct vertical filling between the curves:

```
ListLinePlot[{data[[1]], data[[2]], data[[2, ;; 4]]}, Filling -> {1 -> {3}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, None}]
```

> [image: plot]

---

### Your specific goal

You wrote:

> The best way for defining the filling area would be a straight line between the last points on the two graphs.

Actually it is impossible to achieve this goal with the `Filling` option of `ListLinePlot` because the latter always fills vertically. You need to create a `Polygon` and add it as `Prolog` to your plot:

```
ListLinePlot[data, Prolog -> {LightBlue, Polygon[Join[data[[1]], Reverse@data[[2]]]]}]
```

> [image: plot]

Comment: By my reading of the docs this should work: "In filling between lists of points that do not line up, the stems start at points in the first list, and extend to positions that linearly interpolate between points in the second list. "  This is obviously not true even in simpler (monotonic) cases

Comment: Alexey, already on it. There are two issues here: 1. the extra points (I can't seem to make a simpler example) and 2. the filling which is due to the non-injective nature of the data.

Comment: @rcollyer I have boiled down the minimal example to ``data = {{{45.904, 220.46}, {45.999, 223.72}, {46.02, 235.51}}, {{45.912, 212.72}, {46.019,186.15}, {45.95, 146.43}}}; ListLinePlot[data, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]``.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov that's a nice data set, thanks.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov: The polygon solution works really good for me. Since I'm using the Polygon solution, is Mathematica able to create a polygon around many graphs? Right now, there is a polygon created between 2 data. But if I'm adding another 3 plots (as I mentioned before, there are orginally 5 plots in 1 chart), can I create a polygon which uses always the "most-outside" values? I added a third dataset, that you can see what I mean.

Comment: Alexey, I think this may be a duplicate of [(64988)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64988/121) ?  Would you please consider that example and see if your analysis applies there as well?

Comment: @rcollyer Please take a look also at [this `Filling` bug](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64988/280): addition of `Filling` to rather standard dataset messes up the data.

Answer (score 6):

```
data = {{{45.904`, 227.46`}, {46.012`, 222.72`}, {46.076`, 
     215.51`}, {46.107`, 206.26`}, {46.119`, 196.15`}, {46.119`, 
     186.97`}, {46.118`, 178.5`}, {46.104`, 168.16`}, {46.079`, 
     156.43`}}, {{45.912`, 212.72`}, {45.976`, 205.51`}, {46.007`, 
     196.26`}, {46.019`, 186.15`}, {46.019`, 176.97`}, {46.018`, 
     168.5`}, {46.004`, 158.16`}, {45.979`, 146.43`}}};

Show[
 RegionPlot[
  Polygon[
   Flatten[
    {data[[1]], Reverse[data[[2]]]},
    1]],
  PlotStyle -> LightBlue,
  BoundaryStyle -> None],
 ListLinePlot[
  data,
  PlotStyle -> Thick]]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 although this `RegionPlot` form is still undocumented and the straightforward approach is a little shorter: ``Show[Graphics[{LightBlue,Polygon[Flatten[{data[[1]],Reverse[data[[2]]]},1]]},Frame->True,AspectRatio->1],ListLinePlot[data]]``.

Comment: Thank you for your help Bob Hanlon!