# Filling option generates extra PlotMarkers in ListLinePlot

Tags: plotting, bugs, filling

**Bug introduced in 8 or earlier and fixed in 13.0**

---

Whenever the blue line drops below the orange one MMA (10.0) inserts two additional plotmarkers:

```
ListLinePlot[
 {
  {12., 13., 6., 16., 15., 12., 7., 15., 15., 17.},
  {9., 9., 9., 9., 9., 9., 9., 9., 9., 9.}
  },
 Filling -> {1 -> {2}},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {Automatic, None}},
 GridLines -> {Range@10, Automatic},
 PlotMarkers -> Automatic,
 PlotRange -> {{1, 10}, Automatic}]
```

[image]

Without the `Filling` - option the additional points don't show up:

```
ListLinePlot[
 {
  {12., 13., 6., 16., 15., 12., 7., 15., 15., 17.},
  {9., 9., 9., 9., 9., 9., 9., 9., 9., 9.}
  },
 Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {Automatic, None}},
 GridLines -> {Range@10, Automatic},
 PlotMarkers -> Automatic,
 PlotRange -> {{1, 10}, Automatic}]
```

[image]

Is this a bug?

Is there a workaround?

Comment: Same behavior on v9

Comment: Adding the option `Mesh -> Full` gets rid of the unwanted markers (v9 windows 8).

Comment: I think that this is a bug which is strongly related (but not completely identical) to [this confirmed bug](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92763/280). The common part is that addition of the `Filling` results in extra points included into the plotted lines (what was [confirmed as an issue by rcollyer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92763/listlineplot-filling-wrong/92773#comment252400_92773)). So I add the bugs tag.

Comment: @eldo, the same is even for v6.0! `Mesh->Full` also works =)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In versions from 8 to 10.3 the option `Mesh->Full` gets rid of the unwanted markers:

```
ListLinePlot[{{12., 13., 6., 16., 15., 12., 7., 15., 15., 17.}, {9., 
   9., 9., 9., 9., 9., 9., 9., 9., 9.}}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, 
 Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {Automatic, None}}, 
 GridLines -> {Range@10, Automatic}, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
 PlotRange -> {{1, 10}, Automatic}, Mesh -> Full]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]